# Firebase listeners not responding

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using firebase to develop a realtime chat application.
My listeners (.on / .once) works fine. Except sometimes they don't respond and the application shows blank page. My code is as follows.

```
 // some code here...  $rootScope.register_db.orderByChild("numbers").equalTo(partnerNum).once('value', function(snapshot) {
// Take the snapshot value and do something.
}
```

The application works fine except sometimes listeners dont work and application is stuck at the code just above the listener.
same goes for the .on listener.

```
 $rootScope.DataExchange.orderByChild('to').equalTo(myNum).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
//some code here
}
```

Thanks in advance for Help